# Count first scroll and second scroll events on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to call function when my count is 1 and stop function and when count is 2 want to call another function. My issue is when scroll down just little count becomes 1. if i scroll fast my functions are called but it just called faster.
I have following code.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var count = 0;  
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop){
        console.log('down scroll');
        $(".first_jump").css('background-image', "url('img/bulb2.jpg')");
        count++;
        console.log(count);

        if (count == 1){
            //alert('now');
            $( window ).scrollTop(0);
            return false;
        }
        else if (count == 2){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#home_main").offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        console.log('uop scroll')
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;   
});
```

Comment: can you please post the HTML code

Comment: The issue is because the `scroll` event is fired once for *every pixel* the screen is moved, therefore your methods will both be called after the user has scrolled 2 pixels down the page. What behaviour are you trying to create?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/frwaukjr/2/

Comment: here is my js fiddle link. on scroll it must stop on blue screen and. on third scroll it must go to next div

Comment: what i want is when i scroll down (howsoever fast i go) only the background color of first div should change and scrolling should be disabled for next 5 seconds, after which if i scroll again, i should get smooth scrolled to next div